# MacOS terminal "login: illegal option -- e"

Tags: macos, terminal, command-line, mojave

Whenever I open my terminal on my Mac I get this:

```
login: illegal option -- e
usage: login [-pq] [-h hostname] [username]
    login -f [-lpq] [-h hostname] [username [prog [arg ...]]]

[Process completed]
```

All of the fixes I've tried aren't working. I've tried deleting my preferences for the terminal, changing my shell, and deleting my terminal profile.

How can I resolve this error and get a working shell?

Answer (score 4):

The problem is occurring because of an improper account name beginning with the dash ("-") character. So the solution is changing the name of the account via the steps given in this link: https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT201548

When you open the terminal an automatic login command like `login -pf [account-name]` is executed. Let's say the account name is "-gi". In this case the command will be `login -pf -gi` and naturally, the terminal will show the error `illegal option -- g`. Therefore you should change the account name properly.

Comment: Warning: changing an account's short name (its "Account name") will cause it to loose admin rights; this is not mentioned in the Apple support document. To change an admin account's name, I recommend 1) creating a new temp admin account; 2) removing admin rights from your regular account; 3) renaming the account (see Apple support doc); 4) re-granting admin rights under the account's new name; 5) testing the renamed account (including its admin rights); and optionally 6) deleting the temp admin account.

Answer (score 2):

- Start Terminal (and ignore the error/terminal output)
- Type <kbd>Cmd-,</kbd> to open Preferences
- In the General tab, switch the second option to a custom command and use `/bin/bash -noprofile -norc` as the command
- Switch back to the Terminal window and type <kbd>Cmd-T</kbd> to open a new Terminal tab (which should work now).

Assuming it does

- Run `mv .bashrc{,.OLD}; mv .profile{,.OLD}`
- Switch Preferences back as they have been before
- Debug whatever is in `.bashrc.OLD` and `.profile.OLD` (or just write new files from scratch)