# macOS Big Sur Terminal hangs and no prompt appear

Tags: terminal, performance, iterm, beta-seed-program, big-sur

I have a strange issue on my MacBook Pro (Mid-2017 15" with touch bar; MacBookPro14,3; 11.0 Beta (20A4299v)).

I've just installed macOS Big Sur on an external drive and everything was alright for some time. Terminal app was working perfectly and I still has one window open with it working OK.

The last step I remember doing was downloading and installing iTerm and adding it to the Full Disk Access on Privacy Control Panel before executing it.

After this, every time I open any terminal prompt, with the default app or iTerm, zsh, bash, etc., does not appear, and the window shows login "Terminal - login" and it does not show prompt.

**NOTE:** I know it refers to a beta OS but this problem has already appeared on other macOS versions. I tried the steps on both of these links but none solved it:

- [Launching Terminal Freezes the System for 5 Minutes in Mavericks](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/146798/launching-terminal-freezes-the-system-for-5-minutes-in-mavericks)
- [Terminal login hangs](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/267668/terminal-login-hangs?newreg=8f4e2bdabf3946589f606aaa4152f6d8)

Any ideas?

Answer (score 2):

Typically this is a dot file causing the shell to hang.

1. Make a new account and log out of the old one - log in to the new and open the shell. If it hangs, too - you have system level configuration files to blame in most cases. Reinstall the OS if you can’t Seuss that out.
2. If that works fine, then `su - hanguser` to confirm it’s that one account.
3. [You can run the shell without the rc dot files as well](https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/356778/5472).

Also, before you try anything shut down the OS and validate it happens after a restart, basically try to avoid needing to go through this laundry list of potential issues:

- [Terminal login hangs](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/267668/terminal-login-hangs)

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I've done almost everything both those articles mentions. Also freezes on a fresh account. This is a fresh install on an external disk. My normal macOS Catalina install is ok and works well. So I found this strange because after years using macOS never encountered this.

Answer (score 1):

On one of the articles I’ve mentioned shows a command (`sudo rm -rf /private/var/log/asl/*`). I ran this and reboot. It worked ! I'll update this if the problem returns! Thank you all!

Comment: Could you find this article?  That solution doesn't make sense - the only way I could think log files would cause an issue is if they were consuming too much disk space and the removal of then freed up the space needed.

Comment: https://osxdaily.com/2010/05/06/speed-up-a-slow-terminal-by-clearing-log-files/ may be the article they're referring to